# i want to remove the commas from the value and pass it to soql query how to do it?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Input text field on VF page where user enters value as 1,000,000. i want to remove the commas from the value and pass it to soql query how to do it?

Comment: Use `replaceAll` from here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use String method

> replaceAll(StringToReplace, replaceString) 
>   // ex: myText.replaceAll(',' ,'')

to replace all commas and then can use it in SOQL.

For more reference, check it out https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll